# How to make Twilio Queue Automation Forward

Tags: python, xml, automation, queue, twilio

Can someone tell me please: how to take callers, from enqueue to dial(forwarding). In one app, with automation this ???

i have something like that and it wont work:

```
    <Say>hello</Say>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="https://brass-dragonfly-1957.twil.io/assets/poczekalnia.xml">support</Enqueue>
    <Dial url="/ivr/agent/screencall">
    +000000000
    <Queue>support</Queue>
    </Dial>
    <Redirect>/ivr/welcome/</Redirect>
    </Response>
```

in python look like this:

```
    twiml_response.say('hello')
    twiml_response.enqueue('support', wait_url='https://brass-dragonfly-1957.twil.io/assets/poczekalnia.xml')
    twiml_response.dial('+000000000', url=reverse('ivr:agents_screencall')).queue('support')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to perform actions for both your caller and an agent within the one TwiML response, and that will not work.

When you [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) a caller, no following TwiML will execute until you dequeue the caller with a `<Leave>`.

It looks like you want to dial an agent, allow them to screen the call and then connect them to the caller in the queue. To do this, you would start by [creating a call to your agent using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource). With that call you would provide a URL that will be requested when that agent connects. In the response to that URL you should say the message to them, then [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/queue). Something like this:

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

def call(request):
  twiml_response = VoiceResponse()
  twiml_response.say('hello')
  twiml_response.enqueue('support', wait_url='https://brass-dragonfly-1957.twil.io/assets/poczekalnia.xml')
  call = client.calls.create(
    url = '/agent'.
    to = agent_phone_number,
    from = your_twilio_number
  )
  return HttpResponse(twiml_response, content_type='text/xml')
```

Then, in response to the webhook to the `/agent` endpoint, you should return your response for screening, which might look like this:

```py
def agent(request):
  twiml_response = VoiceResponse()
  gather = Gather(action='/agent_queue', method='POST', numDigits=1)
  gather.say('You are receiving an incoming call, press 1 to accept')
  twiml_response.append(gather)
  return HttpResponse(twiml_response, content_type='text/xml')
```

And finally in `/agent_queue` you determine the result of screening the call and if the agent accepts, then you connect them to the queue.

```py
def agent_queue(request):
  twiml_response = VoiceResponse()
  digits = request.POST.get("Digits", "")
  if digits == "1":
    dial = Dial()
    dial.queue('support')
    twiml_response.append(dial)
  else:
    twiml_response.hangup()
  return HttpResponse(twiml_response, content_type='text/xml')
```

Comment: Ok i make something else but i still have a small problem. I try your soulution but it stops in enqueue and wont call. It is good soulutuon but need to be make in another .py file working infinietly.

NOW everything is correct but this one must be in another file.

And its work propertly with rest code...BUT!:

If one agent pick up i need now add some Code for STOP CALLING I cannot find how to GET all ringing calls and Hangup it

Someone know how to do it ??? how to get all calls ringing and hangout it ??

(ALL CODE soulution in my answer  here)

Comment: The best idea for this is to ask a new question, not to post a question as an answer. Also, if this answer helped, please mark it as correct so that others can see it helped too. Thanks!

Comment: OK sorry im new here - i just think it is Continuation of this problem - but OK!

For everyone who see this answer!!! :
It is good BUT !!! 
You must put MAKE CALL to another file !!! as another program !!! then it works !!!!